# How to Access Map of List in FTL(Freemarker)

Tags: java, jsp, freemarker

I'm trying to access an object that has fields of type String, Lists and Maps in my ftl file.

```
Configuration configuration = prepareConfiguration();
configuration.setClassForTemplateLoading(this.getClass(), "/");
Map<String, Object> mapVal = new HashMap<String, Object>();
mapVal.put("package", packageListing);
Template template = configuration.getTemplate("listing/listing.ftl");
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
template.process(mapVal, stringWriter);
String string = stringWriter.toString();
```

This is the snippet of my code. I have one field of type

```
Map<String, ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>>
```

in my packageListing object. I'm trying to access the List of Object. Something like `Map.get(Key).get(index)` in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Freemarker [getting a value from a map or array](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_var_sequence) is the same, using square brackets:

```
 packageListing[key][index]
```

> **Retrieving data from a sequence**
>   This is the same as for hashes, but you can use the square bracket syntax only, and the expression in the brackets must evaluate to a number, not a string. For example to get the name of the first animal of the example data-model (remember that the number of the first item is 0, not 1): animals[0].name